# TypeError : Object is not a function due to the order of require commands

Tags: node.js

I have two modules, one is `User.js` and other is `Member.js`. Both define constructor functions `User` and `Member` respectively. So, suppose I am testing `Member` by the following :

```
var User = require('../lib/User.js');      --- a
var Member = require('../lib/Member.js');  --- b

var m = new Member({ endpoint:'http://localhost:8001/3.0',
                          username : 'restadmin',
                          password : 'restpass',
                        },
            'http://localhost:8001/3.0/members/106895033442048746754783910678565967857');


m.getInfo().then(function() {
    console.log(m.user);
});
```

The problem is the order of the two require statements `(a)` and `(b)` , if I require `Member` before `User` everything works fine else a `TypeError: object is not a function is thrown.`

I logged `User` in the `Member` module to check if it is constructor or not, it comes out to be `{}`. That's why the error.

### Implementation details :

- [Member.js](https://gitlab.com/black-perl/mailman-client.js/blob/master/lib/Member.js)
- [User.js](https://gitlab.com/black-perl/mailman-client.js/blob/master/lib/User.js)

Comment: The example provided by you looks like a cycle - circular require. You can read more about that here - https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: @mic4ael , yep it is.

Comment: @mic4ael , this worked nice !